# Access 2003: Conditional formatting based on table

Tags: ms-access, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a MS Access 2003 CRM system that sets follow up actions. I need this to use conditional formatting to ensure I don't select a weekend date or something like a bank holiday / annual leave.

I've tried conditional formatting the next action date with the following expression suggested by the designer:

**DLookup(“[OffDates]”, “[tblOffDates]”, “[OffDates]=#” & [the form control name] & “#”)**

However this isn't working. See links below for some context:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2vTy.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy2XP.jpg

I thought it would be simpler to just have it flag up when it matches a date but it's not working. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a DCount, and Test the Expression Is <> 0, then set the conditional format.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a total noob, how would I implement that? What would the code be that I need to put in the conditional formatting box?